# Sum SalesAmount for Next 180 days by ContactID and for each row

Tags: r, data.table

Here is my data frame:

```
df <- read.table(text='
ContactID    ActivityDate   SalesAmount
abc           1/1/2014       1000
abc           5/1/2014       2000
abc           6/10/2014      3000
abc          12/31/2014      4000
xyz           1/1/2014       1000
xyz          5/1/2014        2000
xyz          6/10/2014       3000
xyz          12/31/2014      4000

                    ', header=T)
```

In a previous post, I got help from "Arun" to get the the running total for the last 180 days through this:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[, end := as.Date(ActivityDate, format="%m/%d/%Y")
          ][, start := end - 180L]
setkey(df, ContactID, start, end)
olaps = foverlaps(df, df, nomatch=0L, which=TRUE)
olaps = olaps[xid >= yid, .(ans = sum(df$SalesAmount[yid])), by=xid]

df[olaps$xid, last180 := olaps$ans]
```

I modified the code to get the sum for the next 180 days through this:

```
setDT(df)[, start := as.Date(ActivityDate, format="%m/%d/%Y")
           ][, end := start + 180L]
setkey(df, ContactID,  start,end)
olaps = foverlaps(df, df, nomatch=0L, which=TRUE)
olaps = olaps[xid >= yid, .(ans = sum(df$SalesAmount[yid])), by=xid]

df[olaps$xid, next180 := olaps$ans]
```

But I get the exact same result with next180 as in last180. What am I doing wrong? I am also open to any other fast creative solution to the sum for next 180 days problem.

Comment: @Arun Hi arun. Nothing actually. I thought a creative solution for this problem can come from people who use dplyr heavily.

Comment: @Arun thanks. duly noted and tags changed.

Comment: @Arun. Yep that was it. Thanks a lot. Is there a way for me to accept your answer in comments?

Answer (score 1):

Arun mentioned in comments that I should have  olaps[xid <= yid, ...] instead of olaps[xid >= yid, ...] in my original code for next180. That fixed the problem. The credit goes to original provider of the solution "Arun". The final code to get sum for next180 days is:

```
 require(data.table)
    setDT(df)[, start := as.Date(ActivityDate, format="%m/%d/%Y")
               ][, end := start + 180L]
    setkey(df, ContactID,  start,end)
    olaps = foverlaps(df, df, nomatch=0L, which=TRUE)
    olaps = olaps[xid <= yid, .(ans = sum(df$SalesAmount[yid])), by=xid]

    df[olaps$xid, next180 := olaps$ans]
```

and then

```
df[, c("start", "end") := NULL]
```

if you want to get rid of 'start' and 'end'